# How does the trick used in this question work?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In this guided question, we are asked to show that given that a sequence $a_n$ as a limit $a$, that the sequence $a_n^2$ will have the limit $a^2$.
[image]

I understand how we get to equation 3; we are using the fact that we know the validity of equation 2 and some not very difficult manipulation. Using equation 3 we would now be able to find an $\eta$ for which equation 3 would hold. However, I do not in the least understand the trick that has been used to find this $\eta$. I do not see how choosing $\eta$ to be a particular value, like $|a|$, does not give up generality. If we can chose $\eta<|a|$, can we chose $\eta<5000$ and still find a valid $\eta$?

Answer (score 1):

They make it appear more complicated than it is : $$|a_n^2-a^2|=\underbrace{|a_n-a|}_{<\eta}\underbrace{|a_n+a|}_{<C}<C\eta\to 0$$

- The first inequality is due to $a_n\to a$
- The second one is because a convergent sequence is bounded

Indeed $|a_n-a|<\eta\implies |a_n+a|=|a_n-a+2a|\le|a_n-a|+2|a|\le \eta+2|a|$

And since $\eta$ is arbitrary small, we can choose $\eta<1$ for instance and get a constant $C=1+2|a|$.

*Note:*

*in the book they choose $\eta<|a|$ but this will work only if $a\neq 0$, so I also prefer using $\eta<1$ for better generalization, and you are completely fine also by selecting $\eta<5000$ as you suggested, all that matter is that it is a constant quantity. Most of the time we choose $1$ because, well..., what's simpler than $1$ ?*

Second remark, notice that I haven't even used epsilon on my presentation.

$|a_n^2-a^2|<C\eta$ is by itself sufficient to show the convergence as long as $C$ is a constant.

It is just an aesthetic thing to "normalize" to a bare epsilon, by selecting $\eta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}C)$

---

Edit:

In the definition of a limit we have that provided $n$ is large enough (i.e. $\forall n>N$) then $a_n$ can be made arbitrary close to $a$ (i.e. $|a_n-a|<\eta$).

The term "arbitrary close" means that whatever small $\eta$ is chosen, there is always an $N$ that fulfils the condition.

In particular it is not hindering to have a condition $|a_n-a|<1$ or $|a_n-a|<\text{some positive constant}$, since it will automatically be verified when $\eta$ will get small enough.

In the expression $\eta=\min(1,\epsilon)$ generally $\epsilon\ll 1$ and $\eta=\epsilon$, but from a theoretical point of view, since we put $\forall\epsilon$, it can be any value, and we have to use the min.

Think of it in practical terms. You are driving to the train station (your limit), so there is a moment you will be closer than $1\, km$ (or $1\ mi$) from it, but there will be also another moment were you will be only $1\, m$ (or $1\, yd$) away.

This the same here

- $|a_n-a|\to 0$ so there is some $N_1$ such that $|a_n-a|<1,\forall n>N_1$
- $|a_n-a|\to 0$ so there is some $N_2$ such that $|a_n-a|<\frac \epsilon C,\forall n>N_2$

Overall, there is some $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ such that $|a_n^2-a^2|< C\eta$ for $\eta=\min(1,\frac\epsilon C)$

These min, maw are just there to merge both conditions into a single one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are a few things I am still unsure about. Suppose we do take $\eta<1$. Then we could easily show that $|a_n^2-a^2|<1+2|a|$ but how does this show that this is true for any $\eta$? How does this prove that $C\eta$ goes to zero? I guess what I don't see is how selecting any $\eta$ we want generalizes to all $\eta$ or if it even has to, since the way I understand the definition of convergence is that $\eta$ or $\epsilon$, whichever we are using, should go to zero.

Comment: I attempted to answer this in my edit. I know it is verbose, hope it'll clarify things for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you may have single-handedly saved me from failing my exam tomorrow. I'm curious though, would a valid way to solve to the eq 3 from the book be to move $\epsilon$ to the left: 

$\eta^2+2|a|\eta-\epsilon<0$

and noting that the left hand side always has a positive discriminant, therefore a solution exists, which proves that there must be an $\eta$ that will make $\epsilon$ as small as need be. Would this be also a valid solution?